# What will happen, in my router, if I connect 9V, 0.85A Power adapter to a 12V, 1 A adapter slot?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, adapter, router

I have [NETLINK HG323RGW GPON ONT Router](https://www.netlinkict.com/shop/gpon-ont/gpon-ont-1geife1potswifi/gpon-ont-onu-telephone-internet/), it uses  12V,1A, AC-DC power adaptor. ( Power consumption ≤9W )

I also have TPLINK ADSL Router which uses 9V, 0.85A power Adapter. (  https://www.tp-link.com/la/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/td-w8961nd/#specifications  )

The Adapter cord is short for NETLINK router.

What will happen if I connect 9V, 0.85A Power adapter to a 12V, 1 A adapter slot ?

Comment: Nobody can possibly know what will happen. Therefore, vote to close.

Comment: It might work. It might not. Worse case is you'll waste a lot of your and other people's time chasing phantom problems where it nearly works. Get another power adapter-they're cheap.

Answer (score 1):

It might look like it works - but it might not work at all, or be intermittent; you're not able to supply enough power from the smaller supply.

Why not just get the right power supply from Amazon or something?